# Creating MUC using smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm trying to create a multi-user chat in XMPP and have some confusions.

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(conn1, "myroom@conference.jabber.org");
muc.create("testbot");
muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
```

This is the basic code I found on http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html

Here what is "myroom@conference.jabber.org" and "testbot"? What is the difference between those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myroom@conference.jabber.org` is the MUC room (or the MUC address if you want). Looking at the javadoc for [`MulitUserChat.create(String nickname)`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#create%28java.lang.String%29):

> Creates the room according to some default configuration, 
>   ... 
>   Parameters:
>      nickname - the nickname to use.

**So you are joining myroom@conference.jabber.org with the nickname "testbot"**